# Написание тригеров на MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Приветсвую всех, нужно написать четыре тригера, два из них я сделал, с другими запара, не получается.

1)Запрет на измение ФИО студента.

```
CREATE TRIGGER u_Студенты ON Студента
FOR UPDATE
AS
IF UPDATE (Фамилия)
  OR UPDATE (Имя)
  OR UPDATE (Отчество)
BEGIN
PRINT N'Нельзя изменить ФИО студента'
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END
```

2)Запрет на добавление студента, который уже сущетсвует в БД

```
СREATE TRIGGER i_Студенты ON Студенты
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
IF 2 = (SELECT COUNT(C.[ID Студента])
FROM Студенты AS C, INSERTED AS I
WHERE C.Фамилия LIKE I.Фимилия
AND C.Имя LIKE I.Имя AND C.Отчество LIKE I.Отчество)
BEGIN
PRINT N'Студент уже есть в базе данных'
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END
```

Прошу помочь с ним

3)Запрет на зачисление в группу студента, который обучается в настоящее время в другой группе[image: Так выглядит таблица студенты в группах]

4)Запрет на пересдачу предмета на худшую оценку [image: Так выглядит таблица зачетная ведомость]

P.S свои тригеры добавил для проверки, мб можно что-то улучшить или изменить)

Comment: *IF 2 = (SELECT COUNT(C.[ID Студента])* - в общем случае неверно. А если в БД по каким-то причинам уже дубликат? триггер не сработает, и дубликаты продолжат плодиться.

Comment: *Запрет на зачисление в группу студента, который обучается в настоящее время в другой группе* Вставка - не пройдёт из-за триггера 2. Изменение - легитимно, поскольку удалит студента из старой группы, и в финальном состоянии он будет опять только в одной группе. Вывод - триггер не нужен.

Comment: *Запрет на пересдачу предмета на худшую оценку* INSERT опять запрещён. Значит, опять чисто на UPDATE - только сравнить оценку в INSERTED и DELETED.

Comment: @Akina Как бы ты изменил тригер на запрет на добавление студента, который уже сущетсвует в БД

Comment: Вместо `2=(..)` написал бы `1<(..)`.